# How to refresh the page after conform pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I click the delete button it will conform pop up - if I choose "YES" then success msg wil be shown "Module has been deleted".

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#example tbody").on('click', '.user-Delete', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var getId = $(this).data('id');
      swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text: "You will not be able to recover this Module!",
          type: "warning",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
          confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
          cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          closeOnCancel: false
        },
        function (isConfirm) {
          if (isConfirm) {
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '@Url.Action("DeleteModule")',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {
                ModuleID: getId
              },
              success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                  swal({
                    title: "Deleted!",
                    text: "Module has been deleted.",
                    type: "success",
                    confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
                  });

                }
              },
              error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Sub Categories : ' + ex);
              }
            });

          } else {
            swal({
              title: "Cancelled",
              text: "Module Record is safe :)",
              type: "error",
              confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger"
            });
          }
        });
    });
});
```

[image: delete]

Inside the message popup if I choose ok button then only page should refresh.

[image: sucess]

when I click `OK` then refresh the page

Comment: location.reload();?

Comment: I suspect you'd just refresh the page in your final AJAX success handler, wouldn't you?  Did you try that?  (Though, if you want to reload the page, why use AJAX?)

Comment: @NitinDhomse  `success: function (data) {
 if (data.success) {swal({title: "Deleted!", text: "Module has beendeleted.",
 type: "success", confirmButtonClass: "btn-success", });
 location.reload();  } }`

Comment: if i use this code automatically reload @NitinDhomse

Comment: @NitinDhomse  when i click OK then refresh the page

Comment: Write the click handler of your "Ok" button and call location.reload()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        swal({ 
                title: "Deleted!", 
                text: "Module has been deleted.", 
                type: "success",
                confirmButtonClass: "btn-success", 
            }, 
            function(){ 
                location.reload(); 
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```js
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your swal() call within the success block:

```
  success: function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
      swal({
        title: "Deleted!",
        text: "Module has been deleted.",
        type: "success",
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-success",
      })
      .then(function() {
        location.reload();
      });

    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below javascript function on ok button click

```js
alert("page refresh")

function refresh() {

    setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload()
    }, 100);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="ok" id="submit" onclick="refresh()">
```